# Bootstrap grid columns not working correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a page where there are three main pieces: Below I've called them classes `.one`, `.two`, and `.three`.  These three divs stack on top of each other on mobile (xs), but on the `sm` view `.three` should go to the right as a sidebar while `.one` and `.two` should remain stacked.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row one">
        <div class="one col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row two">
        <div class="two">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2" id="Prev">
                left arrow
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4" id="Next">
                right arrow
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row three">
        <div class="three col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!--container -->
```

Visually, its like this: 
`.one col-sm-8`   `.three col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1` 
`.two col-sm-2`*2

I tried to accomplish this without rows, but the left arrow `.two col-sm-6` filled in to the right of `.one col-sm-8` and left the other two divs below it.  With the three rows, `.three col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1` does not properly rise beside `.one col-sm-8`.  How can I make these columns work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
          <div class="row one">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><div> lorem ipsum </div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row two">
            <div class="col-xs-6" id="Prev">left arrow</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" id="Next">right arrow</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="three col-xs-12 col-sm-3">lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
</div>
```